# Call a method that inside a nested static class from the outer class by using a trait

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I have a static class, 'Inner', and a nested static class, 'Deeper', in two different classes A,B. 'Inner' class implements the trait C that has a method called ping().
I want to execute the method hello() (that belongs to Deeper) from the ping() method in a way that each time I'll get either 'Hello A' or 'Hello B' according to the class that invoked the trait.
This is what I wrote (I'm using katalon-studio):

```
public class A
{
  static class Inner implements C{
     static class Deeper{ 
         static void hello(){ println 'Hello A'}
    }
  }
}
public class B
{
  static class Inner implements C{
     static class Deeper{ 
         static void hello(){ println 'Hello B'}
    }
  }
}
public static trait C {
     static void ping() {
          this.Deeper.hello()
     }
}

A.Inner.ping()
B.Inner.ping()
```

I got the following error:

> 08-17-2018 04:46:57 PM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/V2/General/Draft FAILED
>   because (of) Variable 'Deeper' is not defined for test case.

Comment: What about `this.getClass()`? Or checking the stack of `Thread.currentThread()`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
class A implements C {}
class B implements C {}

trait C { 
    def whoAmI() {
        this.class.simpleName
    } 
}

// ---- main

assert "A" == new A().whoAmI() 
assert "B" == new B().whoAmI()
```

Comment: Where did you define simpleName?

Comment: `getSimpleName()` is a method on `Class` in Java; in Groovy, we can shorten getters from `x.getFoo()` to `x.foo` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()

Comment: Your code is working but when I'm trying to implement it in my script I get 'Class' in return.

Comment: Can you please update the question so that reflects your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an answer for this. However, using non-static classes, this could be implemented as follows:

```
public class A{
   class Inner implements C{
      A.Inner.Deeper d = new A.Inner.Deeper()
      class Deeper { 
          void hello(){ 
             println 'Hello A'  
          }
      }
   }
}
public class B{
   class Inner implements C{
      B.Inner.Deeper d = new B.Inner.Deeper()
      class Deeper{ 
          void hello(){ 
             println 'Hello B' 
          }
      }
   }
}

public trait C{
      public void ping(){
         this.d.hello()
      }
}

new A.Inner().ping()
new B.Inner().ping()
```